# Connect to SQL via ODBC using a .bat

Tags: sql, batch-file, odbc

I am currently performing a SQL query using Oracle SQL Developer and pasting in a standard query (same SELECT every time), then exporting to a csv file. I would like to execute the query via a batch file and place the output in a specified folder. I already use many batch files on this machine and would like to make this query part of a routine.

My machine has an existing ODBC connection to "WHPROD", but I do not know how to use it. Is there a way to connect to WHPROD from a batch file?

Comment: take a look at SQLCMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly possible in batch script directly without going overcomplicated

However it is simple to do it with VBscript, and since you can call your VBscript from a batch script, the result will be exactly what you want.

Here's an example of how to connect to Oracle and retrieve the results of a SELECT from VBS : ([source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12165/Access-Oracle-without-tnsnames-ora))

```
Dim strCon

strCon = “Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; ” & _
         “CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=” & _
         “(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)” & _
         “(HOST=Server_Name)(PORT=1521))” & _
         “(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DB_Name))); uid=system;pwd=system;”

Dim oCon: Set oCon = WScript.CreateObject(“ADODB.Connection”)
Dim oRs:  Set oRs  = WScript.CreateObject(“ADODB.Recordset”)
oCon.Open strCon

Set oRs = oCon.Execute(“SELECT name from v$database”)

While Not oRs.EOF
   WScript.Echo oRs.Fields(0).Value
   oRs.MoveNext
Wend
oCon.Close

Set oRs = Nothing
Set oCon = Nothing
```

And here's how to call your VBS from the batch script :

```
@echo off

start "C:\\yourbatchfolder\\yourscript.vbs"
```

Answer (score 0):

I [wrote an in-depth batch script](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/3792028) once that builds a MSSQL database.  There are lots of great hints in that script that may help you get going.

The script is not specifically using ODBC but I do believe SQLCMD args can be changed to use a ODBC defined connection?  That may work for you; and not just on MSSQL server.